# How to modify ifc file with xbim explorer

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

When I add an element to an ifc file, I have always a newer ifcownerhistory, person and organization created. I open my file ifc file with .Net xbim xplorer like this, and I save the default ownerhistory for reuse it when I create a new element:

```
   private ObjectDataProvider ModelProvider
   {
       get
       {
           return MainFrame.DataContext as ObjectDataProvider;
       }
   }
   
   public IfcStore Model
   {
       get
       {
           var op = MainFrame.DataContext as ObjectDataProvider;
           return op == null ? null : op.ObjectInstance as IfcStore;
       }
   }
public bool LoadIFC()
{
    var model = IfcStore.Open(currentFileName);
    SetContext(model);
    if (Model != null)
    {
        owner = Model.Instances.OfType<IIfcOwnerHistory>().First();
        version = Model.SchemaVersion;
    }
}

private void SetContext(IfcStore model)
{
    var context = new Xbim3DModelContext(model);
    context.CreateContext();  
    ModelProvider.ObjectInstance = model;
    ModelProvider.Refresh();
}
```

Here is my code to add a task which work with ifcstore but not with memorymodel:

```
private void AddTask()
{
    if (_currentProduct == null) return;

        using (var txn = Model.BeginTransaction("Ajout IfcTask a un produit"))
        {
            try
            {
                
                IfcTask newIfcTask = Model.Instances.New<IfcTask>();
                newIfcTask.Name = "Test";
                newIfcTask.Description = "TaskDescription";
                newIfcTask.OwnerHistory = (IfcOwnerHistory)owner;
                
                IfcTaskTime taskTime = Model.Instances.New<IfcTaskTime>();
                taskTime.EarlyStart = new IfcDateTime(StartDate.ToString());
                taskTime.EarlyFinish = new IfcDateTime(EndDate.ToString());
                
                newIfcTask.TaskTime = taskTime;
                
            
                IfcRelAssignsToProduct relAssignsToProduct = Model.Instances.New<IfcRelAssignsToProduct>();
                relAssignsToProduct.RelatingProduct = _currentProduct;
                relAssignsToProduct.RelatedObjects.Add(newIfcTask);
               
                txn.Commit();
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Erreur lors de la création de l'IfcTask : " + ex.Message);
                txn.RollBack();
            }
        }
}`
```

I want to reuse the default ownerhistory, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing an IFC model with xbim you should always perform edits in a transaction, and commit the transaction before saving the model. Otherwise your edits will not be persisted.

So for example

```cs
            //Begin a transaction as all changes to a model are ACID
            using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Edit Model"))
            {

                //create a project
                var wall = model.Instances.New<IfcWall>();
                //and further set properties, relationships
                
                //now commit the changes, else they will be rolled back at the end of the scope of the using statement
                txn.Commit();
            }
            return model; 
            // then Save the model
```

If you're using `IfcStore` for your IModel implementation then all edits will automatically be linked with a new *IfcOwnerHistory*

If that's not what you want there are a couple of options:

1. Use `MemoryModel` or `EsentModel` - neither of which add this convenience mechanism to assign edits to an OwnerHistory
2. Subscribe to the IModel.EntityModified event handler, and post-fix the OwnerHistory
3. Log an issue (and ideally a Pull Request) to make [IfcStore.ManageOwnerHistory](https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimEssentials/blob/ac8b9092b87ae401d91d53578388b2b746c26852/Xbim.Ifc/IfcStore.cs#L420C23-L420C42) public and settable, so you can skip this behaviour.

Comment: Thank but i know this , the problem after the comit and save, i have always new ownerhistory added on my ifc file

Comment: OK, well that's technically correct but I guess there may be cases where you don't want that audit capability? I'll update the Answer with some options

Comment: thank for your advice , but I can't find any help to do this

Comment: In `LoadIfc()` just change from using IfcStore to `var model = MemoryModel.OpenRead(currentFilename)`.

Comment: Now i can use setContext and see the 3d model on the viewer.

Comment: And other problem i can't use Model.Instances.New<IfcRelAssignsToProduct>()

Comment: Maybe raise another question providing the details. E.g. provide code, explain the issue and what you expect. S/O comments are not really the place for debug sessions.

Comment: More generally it's not very clear what you're trying to achieve, and why you're making these changes within the xbim Xplorer codebase. Xplorer is quite a complex app and it feels like you need to start with something more simple / standalone initially - and then maybe integrate. E.g. Xplorer has a plugin system for extending the functionality

Comment: Hi ,
I just want add some ifc element without rewrite new ownerhistory , person and organisation , i don't have problem to add different entity when i open the file with ifcstore 
But if i open the file with memorymodel , i have two other problem , i can create new ifcmaterial , new ifctask but i can't create new IfcRelAssignsToProduct , i have the following error  "Cross model entity assignment"
The second problem , i don't have global id for the different entity wich i can create.

Comment: So , i just updated my post with the code wich fail with memorymodel

Comment: You must be mixing up the Model instances somehow. That's what "Cross model entity assignment" means - adding an element from one model to another.
On GlobalID you can just generate one from a normal Guid: `item.GlobalId = IfcGloballyUniqueId.FromGuid(yourGuid)`

Comment: ok thank for the globalId, but i 'am always stuck for the cross model assignment , and why i don't have this error for the other instances ? i change the order of creation , i have use newIfcTask.Model.BeginTransaction  to be sure i use the same model !   So it true i have the model open twice , one for the drawing3dcontrol named model3d and typed with ifcstore and the other one for make modification.

Comment: I'd guess that _currentProduct belongs to the other model instance. You need to look up the equivalent element in the model you're editing. Sorry this is getting beyond what I can help you with on this medium - have you considered a support contract?

Comment: I also tried to recover the product concerned of the same model and I got the same error.
I don't understand why we can't use the viewer with a memorymodel or manage ownerhistory as we want, in any case thank you for trying to help me